# Atomic writes in linux

Tags: c, linux

On linux, when writing to a pipe, if the data is equal or less than the memory page size (4k atleast on 64bit rhel), the OS provides the guarantee that the whole write will either succeed or fail, but there would be no corruption of data, when multiple process are doing write at the same time. This applies to writing to regular files also.

1. My question is that is this atomicity a feature of virtual memory of linux? If yes, consider  a shared memory scenario between two process, where one process is swapped out in middle of the write by the scheduler. Does Virtual memory subsytem ensures that the memory page to which the process was writing, is also locked, so that the second process cannot write to the same page?
2. Is this atomicity at page level only applicable across process , or also between threads of the same process?

Comment: Normally, the sender and receiver are both locked inside a system call. Inside the system call, the kernel can actually do *anything*. The write starts by copying the userspace buffer into a system buffer. (for which a lock will need to be aquired, and of course: sufficient bufferspace. This could take a few operations, ie to steal some memory for the buffer from other structures or user processes) The user process is only woken up after all the operations by the kernel have been completed. VM is not a *real* issue, since the kernel and user process live in different address spaces

Comment: For pipes you have PIPE_BUF from limits.h, not the memory page size (specified by POSIX).

Comment: @wildplasser based on your explanation, it seems that atomicity would apply not only across process, but also between threads in the same process. Correct?

Comment: Yes. *in principle* all system calls are atomic: either they succeed, or they fail. For the pipe i/O the distinction is made that read/writes upto PIPE_BUFF are atomic. This implies that *if* you try to write a larger size, a buffer written by another process *might be* interleaved with your (two) writes. (this enables the system to obtain one buffer at a time, intead of trying to grab them all in one sweep, while holding a lock) It also avoids buffer suffocation, since (system calls for) other processes are allowed to grab buffers, too.

Comment: @wildplasser Write call provides data and it's size. So why would kernel try to obtain PIPE_BUFF at a time? If the size is 1Mb, it should ask VM for 1Mb. In this way, atleast, some system calls would succeed. For buffer suffocation scenario, consider where large number of system calls are doing writes, greater than PIPE_BUFF. In this case, all calls first obtain PIPE_BUFF amount of memory and then when they try to acquire again, all of them fail. Also asking memory in chunks of PIPE_BUFF could result in getting non contigous memory

Comment: `If the size is 1Mb, it should ask VM for 1Mb.` No, it should not. The syscall API is a *contract* between the OS and the userspace process. This API guarantees that **writes with sizes upto PIPE_BUF are atomic**. What the kernel does after (or before) writing your first buffer is up to the kernel. The only guarantee it gives, is that it won't write only half of the (first) buffer.

Comment: @Jimm: If the kernel did that, any process could DoS the kernel just by making large writes to a pipe.

Answer (score 3):

1. No. If two processes are using shared memory, there is no implicit lock between the processes from this. You will have to arrange such a lock yourself (and if the owner of the lock is swapped out, then your other process will have to darn well wait until the owner gets swapped in and releases the lock after finishing whatever it was doing whilst holding the lock).
2. I don't believe there is any implicit (or explicit) rule that pages are different from other memory overall. The specific rules apply to writing to pipes and files, that if all the data fits in one page, it can be written as one block by the OS - I think you'll find that the OS holds a lock on the resource that it is writing to for one page at a time. If the data is bigger than a page, when the lock is relesed, the other process [or thread] may well be ready to run and thus "steal" the lock from the first process. Less than a page, it does the whole write in one locked run.

But to be clear, there is no implicit locks on writes (or reads) of memory pages in general. It applies strictly to CERTAIN functions. Typically, a particular function will also have a lock of some sort that prevent other processes from running in the same function [at least with a given resource - e.g. a file descriptor or similar - it's perfectly possible that some other process can read from another file simultaneously to your process reading from or writing to your file, but YOUR file is atomic per some size of block that the lock is held for, but not for your "write the entire Shakespeares works at once" system call, as that could potentially block some other important process.

Comment: The latter half of second point explained here was really cool. Defragmented my mind's disk!!